# Hypervisor Installation Failed to update status to COMPLETE

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, hypervisor

Using `Android Studio`, I am trying to install `Android Emulator Hypervisor`. I get the following error message

`Failed to update status to COMPLETE`

The log file `idea.log` has:

`"Install Android Emulator hypervisor driver (installer) v.2.0.0" failed`.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Start `Android Studio` version "Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1"
2. Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools >
3. Unselect `HAXM` to uninstall it
4. select `Android Emulator hypervisor driver (installer)` to install it
5. OK

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio really has a problem with AEHD installation via SDK Manager. You can bypass this issue downloading AEHD from github repository and install manually.
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration

> The Android Emulator hypervisor driver can also be downloaded and installed from GitHub. After unpacking the driver package, run silent_install.bat at a command line with administrator privileges.

Answer (score -1):

I installed BOTH of `HAXM` and `Hypervisor`. It worked! It seems that `Hypervisor` needs `HAXM` to be installed!

Comment: No, AEHD does not need HAXM. AEHD is alternative for HAXM and the way to go. Android Studio really has a problem with AEHD installation via SDK Manager. You can bypass this bug downloading AEHD from github repository and install manually. Read instructions https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration

Comment: @user2051551 Thank you for your feedback. I tried it 3 times. Each time, I tried installing Hypervisor with and without HAXM. So, I concluded it could be the reason for the issue. Thank you for the link to the standard documentation. I would appreciate it if you could point us to the fix for the specific problem I reported. If my suggestion to fix the problem does not cause any harm, I suggest you remove the (-1 - not useful) voting.

Comment: IMHO advise to install two hypervisors is bad idea. I cannot technically undo -1: "Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited"